# how to change the stacked bar chart using ggplot2 (percentage, sort) in R

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am new to R and ggplot2. I have a dataset that I want to visualize with stacked bar chart, where

- x axis is categorical variable (sex)
- bar consists of categorical variable (day)
- y axis should be percentile.

**Example..**

| total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16.99 | 1.01 | Female | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 |
| 10.34 | 1.66 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 |

```
    data(tips, package='reshape2')
    
    ggplot(tips, aes(x=sex)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=day), width = 0.5, position = 'fill')+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6))
```

from here, I want to make the following changes in the chart.

1. to take out **'Fri'** from the chart, but **the percentage of the other days should remain same**. This means the percentage of 'Sat, Sun, Thur' is not re-mapped to 100%
2. to **sort the 'sex'** with descending order of 'Sat' percentage. This means, if 'Male' has higher percentage of 'Sat' than the one of 'Female', 'Male' should come on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data(tips, package='reshape2')

tips %>% 
  #Calculating percentage by sex outside ggplot2
  count(sex,day) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(p = 100*n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  #Removing Friday 
  filter(day != "Fri") %>% 
  #Ordering sex by Saturday percentage
  mutate(
    sex = fct_reorder2(
    .f = sex,
    .x = p,
    .y = day,
    .fun = function(x,y) max(x[y == "Sat"])
      )
    ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = p)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=day))
```